# How Do I monitor progess and recover in a long-running Spark map job?

Tags: apache-spark

We're using Spark to run an ETL process by which data gets loaded in from a massive (500+GB) MySQL database and converted into aggregated JSON files, then gets written out to Amazon S3.

My question is two-fold:

1. This job could take a long time to run, and it would be nice to know how that mapping is going. I know Spark has a built in log manager. Is it as simple as just putting a log statement inside of each map? I'd like to know when each record gets mapped.
2. Suppose this massive job fails in the middle (maybe it chokes on a DB record or the MYSQL connection drops). Is there an easy way to recover from this in Spark? I've heard that caching/checkpointing can potentially solve this, but I'm not sure how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like 2 questions with lost of answers and detail. Anyway, assuming non-SPARK Streaming answer and referencing other based on my own reading / research, a limited response:

1. The following on logging progress checking of stages, tasks, jobs:

   - Global Logging via log4j and tailoring of this by using under the template stored  under SPARK_HOME/conf folder, the template log4j.properties.template file which serves as a basis for defining logging requirements for ones own purposes but at SPARK level.
   - Programmtically by using Logger, using import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}.
   - REST API to get status of SPARK Jobs. See this enlightening blog: http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api
   - There is also a Spark Listener that can be used
   - :http://:8080 to see progress via Web UI.
2. Depends on type of failure. Graceful vs. non-graceful, fault tolerance aspects or memory usage issues and things like serious database duplicate key errors depending on API used.

   - See [How does Apache Spark handles system failure when deployed in YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762672/how-does-apache-spark-handles-system-failure-when-deployed-in-yarn) SPARK handles its own failures by looking at DAG and attempting to reconstruct a partition by re-execution of what is needed. This all encompasses aspects under fault tolerance for which nothing needs to be done.
   - Things outside of SPARK's domain and control mean it's over. E.g. memory issues that may result from exceeding various parameters on at large scale computations, DF JDBC write against a store with a duplicate error, JDBC connection outages. This means re-execution.

As an aside, some aspects are not logged as failures even though they are, e.g. duplicate key inserts on some Hadoop Storage Managers.

Comment: Great answer! This helped guide me a lot. I have setup logging using log4j and just log things inside of my map and reduce functions to ensure it's all mapping properly as it goes.

Also, for failures I found an article that recommneded using accumulators for handling errors gracefully. I end up passing around an accumulator and collecting failed records. That way the rest of the job can run and I can come back and fix the broken records in a subsequent run.

Comment: Good on you Sir, many ways to skin the vat - I am a cat lover though!